# A RenderFlex overflowed by 40 pixels on the bottom while i am using trailing with new column

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am using trailing with new column to put two arrows up and down in shopping cart.
I am facing a problem doing this.
I will post my code.**

> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> ```
> class Cart_products extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _Cart_productsState createState() => _Cart_productsState();
> }
>
> class _Cart_productsState extends State<Cart_products> {
>   var products_on_the_carts = [
>     {
>       "name": "Blazer",
>       "picture": "images/products/blazer.jpg",
>       "price": 80,
>       "size": "M",
>       "color": "black",
>       "quantity": 1,
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Shoes",
>       "picture": "images/products/hills1.jpeg",
>       "price": 100,
>       "size": "38",
>       "color": "red",
>       "quantity": 1,
>     },
>   ];
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return new ListView.builder(
>         itemCount: products_on_the_carts.length,
>         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>           return new Single_cart_products(
>             cart_product_name: products_on_the_carts[index]["name"],
>             cart_product_color: products_on_the_carts[index]["color"],
>             cart_product_quantity: products_on_the_carts[index]["quantity"],
>             cart_product_size: products_on_the_carts[index]["size"],
>             cart_product_price: products_on_the_carts[index]["price"],
>             cart_product_picture: products_on_the_carts[index]["picture"],
>           );
>         });
>   }
> }
>
> class Single_cart_products extends StatelessWidget {
>   final cart_product_name;
>   final cart_product_picture;
>   final cart_product_price;
>   final cart_product_size;
>   final cart_product_color;
>   final cart_product_quantity;
>
>   Single_cart_products({
>     this.cart_product_name,
>     this.cart_product_picture,
>     this.cart_product_price,
>     this.cart_product_size,
>     this.cart_product_color,
>     this.cart_product_quantity
> });
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Card(
>       child: ListTile(
>         leading: new Image.asset(cart_product_picture),
>         title: new Text(cart_product_name),
>         subtitle: new Column(
>           children: <Widget>[
>             new Row(
>               children: <Widget>[
>                 // product size
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
>                   child: new Text("Size:"),
>                 ),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
>                   child: new Text(cart_product_size, style: TextStyle(color:Colors.red),),
>                 ),
>
>                 // product color
>                 new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
>                   child: new Text("Color:"),),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
>                   child: new Text(cart_product_color, style: TextStyle(color:Colors.red),),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             ),
>
>             // product price
>             new Container(
>               alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
>               child: new Text("\$${cart_product_price}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color:
> ```
>
> Colors.red),),
> )
> ],
> ),
> trailing: new Column(
> children: [
> new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up) ,onPressed: (){}),
> //new Text("$cart_product_size"),
> new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down) ,onPressed: (){}),
> ],
> ),
> ),
> );
> }
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
trailing: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(child: Text("$cart_prod_qty")),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```